# How to send a DELETE request Using QNetworkAccessManager?

Tags: c++, qt, rest, qnetworkaccessmanager

I am using QNetworkAccessManager to POST, PUT, and GET data from the server. The code looks like below.

```
QNetworkAccessManager *manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);

connect(manager, SIGNAL(proxyAuthenticationRequired(const QNetworkProxy &, QAuthenticator *)), 
  SLOT(slotProxyAuthenticationRequired(const QNetworkProxy &, QAuthenticator *)));
connect(manager, SIGNAL(authenticationRequired(QNetworkReply *, QAuthenticator *)), 
  SLOT(slotAuthenticationRequired(QNetworkReply *, QAuthenticator *)));

QNetworkRequest request;

request.setUrl(m_url);
request.setRawHeader("User-Agent", "Qt NetworkAccess 1.3");

m_pReply = manager->get(request);
m_pReply = manager->post(request,"name=someName");
m_pReply = manager->put(request,"name=someName");
```

I am Not able to find any delete methods for the request .Yes I found  manager->deleteResource(request)

But is there any

```
manager->delete(request,"name=someName")
```

method in Qt? Or is there any other method for deleting the data on the basis of e.g name?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since `delete` is a reserved word in C++, the corresponding method of `QNetworkAccessManager` is called `deleteResource`.

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtnetwork/qnetworkaccessmanager.html#deleteResource